# How to run word count example in cassandra with hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, count, cpu-word, cassandra

I can run word count using hadoop and I want to use cassandra with hadoop now. I want to run word count example in cassandra but I could not understand how to do it. I read through readme file in the example but it does not mention about how to or when to start hadoop. I am a bit confused. How can I do that? Step by step explanation would be very helpful.

Regards,

Comment: Did you try anything? Posting here would help. Have a look at the link below, check the section at the very end. http://www.xmsxmx.com/apache-whirr-create-hadoop-cluster-automatically/

Answer (score -2):

I did that once and took some notes here

http://blog.alvazan.com/165/how-to-set-up-the-cassandra-wordcount-example/

Comment: Your blog is not loading. This might help others: http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2011/01/apache-cassandra-map-reduce-example.html